# Can I use Spring caching abtraction with condition on a method that returns a Mono?

Tags: java, spring, caching, reactor

I have the method as:

```java
public Mono<ClientResponse> getRepositoryDetails(@NotNull String owner, @NotNull String repositoryName)
```

I would like to cache the response only if it's 2xx. Is it possible to use Spring abstraction for that?

Sth like:

```java
@CachePut(value = "github_api_cache", key = "#owner + '_' + #repositoryName", condition = "#result != null && #result.block().statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()")
```

But I don't want to and anyway I cannot use `block()`

For now I resigned from caching abstraction and I'm just using Cache directly:

```java
 final Mono<ClientResponse> res = this.webClient.get()
                .uri(this.uri, owner, repositoryName, clientId, clientSecret)
                .ifNoneMatch(etag)
                .exchange();

return res.doOnNext(response -> {
            if (response.statusCode().isError()) {
                throw WebClientResponseException.create(response.rawStatusCode(),
                        "Cannot get repository details, expected 2xx HTTP Status code", null, null, null
                );
            }

            if (response.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                this.cache.put(owner + "_" + repositoryName, res.cache());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this without block, I think your way is something that I would do too. Just a point about your question, for compare result in Spring is `unless` property, then you should invert the condition of the example.
There are https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons that have some cache features that you could use too.